# Flutter Resolves to Wrong Path

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor, flutter-path

I'm not really sure what I did, but it seems like I ended up making the path of flutter split into two different places, and the flutter SDK Checkout is not in the right one. I've been trying for hours to fix it. This is what flutter doctor shows. [My Flutter Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ98L.png). Also, here is my .zshrc file.[.zshrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q97qX.png)

So far, I've tried editing the path using export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
I've also edited the .zschrc file to change the path there, and I've once tried PATH="$PATH:/Users/artemis1/applications/flutter/bin, but so far, the same warning still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update $PATH according to the warning message, you will have to put the desired path in front of the existing $PATH.

That is

```
export PATH="/Users/artemis1/applications/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

The paths inside $PATH are used in the order they are listed.

---

Aside from that you will probably want to maintain only one installation of flutter and delete the other.